# c++ convert character to integer using ASCII

Tags: c++, ascii

I am working on a little c++ project that receives a char array input from the user. Depending on the value, I am converting it to an int. I understand there are better ways of doing this but I thought I'd try to convert it through ASCII to allow other uses later on. My current code for the conversion is:-

```
int ctoi(char *item){
    int ascii, num = 0;
    ascii = static_cast<int>(item[0]);
    if(ascii >= 49 && ascii <=57){
        num = ascii - 48;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

    ascii = static_cast<int>(item[1]);
    if(ascii >= 48 && ascii <=57){
        num = num * 10;
        num = num + (ascii - 48);
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
    return num;
}
```

It receives a input into the char array item[2] in the main function and passes this to the conversion function above. The function converts the first char to ASCII then the decimal value of the ASCII to num if its between 1 and 9, then it converts the second char to ASCII, if it is between 0 and 9, it times the value in num by 10 (move along one unit) and adds the decimal value of the ASCII value. At any point it may fail, it returns the value 0 instead.

When I cout the function after receiving a value and run this code in a console, it works fine for single digit numbers (1 - 9), however when I try to use a double digit number, it repeats digits such as for 23, it will output 2233.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Pro tip: don't use `48`, `49`, `57`, etc - use `'0'`, `'1'`, `'9'`, etc.

Comment: Why don't you use the inbuilt c function atoi or strtoi?

Comment: I've tried this out and it seems to work as you'd expect for me, I can't see any problem (other than there being better ways to do this...). Perhaps the problem is in the code that calls this and displays the result, can you include that?

Comment: @PaulR (1) I *agree*. (2) there are valid use-cases for *not* using char-constants for this, though I seriously doubt the OP's is one of them. Specifically, for having portable code that is processing known-*ASCII* character byte content. Using '0'..etc in-code on a non-ASCII platform when processing such a file not work. But if that were and issue and the OP were programming on said-platforms, I doubt they're be asking this question (thus why I agree). Just wanted to mention it.

Comment: I'm still rather new to C++ so I thought it would be a good idea to program this the long way to learn the theory behind it. Also, I would prefer to convert it to a integer as it is used to reference a 2D array that could be very large or small in the end.

Comment: How does this work with even a single digit number? Suppose you pass "5", (bytes: `{ '5', 0 }`). The first test for `item[0]` begin in-range passes, so `num` is set to `5`. The next test for `item[1]` being in-range *fails* and you return `0`. Or I totally read the code wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think you read the code right but maybe the question wrong. As I read the question the array is always two chars long and not containing a nul terminator...just two ascii digits.

Comment: @PaulR And there's no need for the `static_cast<int>`.

Comment: I resolved this by creating a new document and copying the code into there. I think there is an issue with the IDE that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you're reading the input into a two-character array. Note that it's customary to terminate such strings with a null character, which leaves just one for the actual input. In order to read a string in C++, use this code:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
```

Alternatively, for a whole line, use this:

```
std::string line;
getline(std::cin, line);
```

In any case, these are basics explained in any C++ text. Go and read one, it's inevitable!